# Execute unicode command from script on Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, vlc, notepad

I need to execute a command like `vlc 舨.avi` programatically on Windows. When done directly in cmd.exe this works just fine, proving that VLC has the capability to recognize unicode arguments. However, I'm having trouble putting this in a script and having it work.

Has anyone done this successfully? I would love to do this in Ruby (I have 1.9.2) but Python-win32, Perl-win32, batch, .cmd, VB/W/JScript are all options. Target O/Ses are XP and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an encoding issue.

Encoding in command prompts and in windows is not always the same. If your script in Notepad, then execute it, you may end up with the filename being converted to unicode differently hence the error.

Somehow, you'll have to make sure that the encoding is correct, maybe by saving you batch file as Unicode text file? Would that work?

Comment: I have tried using all the Notepad 'save as' options: Unicode/Unicode big endian/UTF-8. The first 2 don't seem to do anything. UTF-8 at least opens VLC, but VLC interprets the filename as ASCII or Windows-1252 or something.